# new and instanceof Javascript

Tags: javascript, new-operator, instanceof

Hi i am fairly new to Javascript. I am a bit confused with the new word and its role in deciding output of instanceof operator.

**Case 1. Returning Object literal**

```
var Dog=function(){
return{legs:4,bark:alert("BOW!!")};};

var luna=Dog();

luna instanceof Dog;//why false here
false

var luna=new Dog();

luna instanceof Dog;//why false here
false
```

**Case 2:Now instead of returning object literal I am doing nothing,**

```
var Dog=function(){
};
var luna=Dog();

luna instanceof Dog
false

var luna=new Dog();

luna instanceof Dog;//why true here
true
```

Comment: Pretty accurate explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> var luna=Dog();
> luna instanceof Dog;//why false here
> ```

Because you:

1. Did not use a `new` operator
2. Returned a simple object

> ```
> var luna=new Dog();
> luna instanceof Dog;//why false here
> ```

Because you returned a simple object which *overrode* the object created by the `new` operator.

> ```
> var luna=new Dog();
> luna instanceof Dog;//why true here
> ```

Because you:

1. Did use a `new` operator
2. Did not override the return value

Comment: Perhaps you could include the association between the new operator and a prototype (which is what instanceof uses).

Comment: @Quentin So is it like this behind the scenes??
var Dog=function(){
var obj=Object.create(Dog.prototype);
return obj;
};

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**

```
var Dog=function(){
return{legs:4,bark:alert("BOW!!")};};

var luna=Dog();
luna instanceof Dog;
false
```

Here you are not instantiating anything, it's just a function that returns a value : a plain Object. This is more or less the equivalent of :

```
var Dog=function(){
return new Object();
}
```

The constructor of the returned value is Object : `luna.constructor` is the `Object()` function.

```
var luna=Dog();
luna instanceof Dog;
false


var luna=new Dog();

luna instanceof Dog;
false
```

You cannot instantiate a function that returns something

**Case 2:**

```
var Dog=function(){
};
var luna=Dog();
```

It is called as a function, a function that does not return anything, actually it returns `undefined`

```
luna instanceof Dog
false
```

because `undefined` is not an instance of anything

```
var luna=new Dog();
```

Creates a new `Object` having Dog as constructor `luna.constructor` is `Dog()`

```
luna instanceof Dog;//luna is an object here
true
```

The new operator is used to specify what the function should do: without it it returns something (or `undefined`), with it it instantiate a new object from the constructor (here `Dog`)

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the `function` keyword to create classes can be confusing. When you call `Dog()` without the `new` keyword, you are doing no more than calling a function; classes are not involved.

In Case 1, the first `luna` is just the result when `Dog` is called as a plain function: `{legs:4, bark: alert("BOW!!")}` and has nothing to do with `Dog` as a class. The same is true of the second `luna`. Since `Dog` returns an object, it overrides the "class" instance that is usually created with `new`.

In Case 2, the first `luna` is just like the first `luna` in case 1, a plain object. But the second `luna` is an instance of `Dog` because the `new` keyword is used, which means `Dog` is treated like a class instead of a function, and nothing is returned from `Dog`.

(Also, you should change the object to `{legs: 4, bark: function() { alert("BOW!!"); }}`.)

Comment: Yeah i was wondering why the hell alert kept executing.Nice!.